# Can the Tor Browser itself hide your location?

Tags: onion-routing, location

I know this is about the simplest of questions, but I've yet to come across an answer that gives me a sold yes or no answer.

Basically, what I'm dealing with are average internet users who claim to be able to figure out my location. I'm not exactly sure how they do it, but my best guess would be is they use one of those "flag counter" things that tells them which country people are visiting from. I've tried using VPNs, which appear to work, but then people still claim to find my location and I still seem to appear on those flag counters.

So I guess my question is, can Tor hide my location, specifically from flag counters (see image below, it is an example from http://flagcounter.com/)?

[image: flag counter]

Comment: Yes, Tor Browser hides your true location from any websites you visit through Tor Browser.

Comment: Right but Tor Browser doesn't tell the site where you're connecting from. The site can only know where you're exiting from, not where you originated from.

Comment: @canonizingironize Could you elaborate on what you mean when you say "where you're exiting from"?

Comment: You connect to the website over a Tor circuit, You -> Guard -> Middle -> Exit -> Website. The website sees Exit but it can't see any further back.

Comment: You can do a check if you want at a few sites, such as https://whatismyipaddress.com, and https://panopticlick.eff.org/tracker-nojs as these will let you test your parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Tor and Tor Browser hide your location from any website. The connections goes through three different relays and the website can only see the relay where your connection is exiting. However when you look at the [bubble graphs sorted by country](https://metrics.torproject.org/bubbles.html#country-exits-only) you'll find that a huge percentage of relays is in the USA, Romania, Netherlands and Germany. So if you're living in the US and look at the flag counter there is a high chance that the flag counter says you're from the US, because the exit lives in the US. But in this example it doesn't know your real location.

Whener you visit a website with the Tor Browser you can click on the green onion and see where your connection currently exits.