# How is a site tracing my location on tor?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, anonymity, mac, location

On walmart.ca, my location data shows up.

[image: Tor circuit view]

I'm using the latest version of TBB 6.5.2 on MacOS Sierra 10.12.4. I am not signed in and it happens during a new start of Tor. The browser is on medium security.

How is walmart.ca seeing my true location?

edit: different country node: website shows my city location from any exit node
https://i.stack.imgur.com/nopEA.jpg

edit2: I can't connect to the site anymore.

edit3: I can still connect to walmart.ca and it shows my true city location over different exit nodes. I click through different exit nodes to get through the Access Denied screen. I noticed initially because the site went through the first time I tried it.

I am not typing in any info or signing in. Walmart.ca auto enters my city postal code.

~Thanks for the help guys

Comment: Part of your question is probably also answered here: https://tor.stackexchange.com/q/14493/88

Comment: I tried from a number of different Tor exits to visit walmart.ca, but I got "Access Denied" from all. Does the behavior yo report persist over time, and across many different exit nodes? It is also (remotely) possible that walmart.ca is reporting Vancouver simply because someone on that Tor exit recently did something to indicate that they were in Vancouver.

Comment: It's just the default, it gives me the same location.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I finally managed to find an Exit that wallmart.ca didn't block.

That post code is just the default. Purely co-incidence if it happens to match where you are actually located.

The website has no idea of your real location.

[image: Default location]

Comment: It shows with any node. The node in the picture is halfway across the country. Vancouver - Montreal.

Comment: oh, youre typing in a postcode.